# Creating custom formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a custom formula to get the number of "Pass" I need in order to get a rating of greater than 96%. So we get the rating by dividing the number of "Pass" you got with the total number of items checked.
Sample:

```
numPass = 31
numTotal = 35
rating = (31/35)*100 = 89% (rounded off)
```

So with the example above, I want to know how much more "numPass" I need in order to get the rating greater than 96%.

I figured out how to do it manually though. I need to keep incrementing numPass and numTotal until it results in a value greater than 96. Found a way to do it via app script but for some reason, it's going in an infinite loop. LOL! Here's my code below:

```
function passNeeded(numPass, numTotal){
var numPass = 31;
var numTotal = 35;
var avg = (numPass/numTotal)*100

while (avg.toFixed(0) < 96){
numPass++;
numTotal++;
}
return numPass;
}
```

Don't really know where I'm doing it wrong as it's my first time with app script and it will be really great if you can help me out on this.

Comment: you dont recalculate avg after you increment. add `avg = (numPass/numTotal)*100` inside while loop after you increment both numPass and numTotal

Comment: OMG that actually fixed it! hahahah thanks soo much!